# SQL Like with comma separated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query which involves retrieving record(s) that matches a comma delimited search string,

e.g. Keying 'wis' will return

WIS82763

and 'wis,sun' will return

WIS82763 &
SUN37483

I was using `( T.ReceiptNo  LIKE  '%' + @ReceiptNo + '%' )` but apparently it's not going to work with comma delimited string. I tried many different combination and variation but none is giving me the desired result. Please kindly advice.

Comment: Is it just your search string that's comma separated, or do you have comma-separated values in the database?

Comment: @a1ex07 Looks like T-SQL syntax. I'm re-tagging this sql-server. OP feel free to correct the tag if it's wrong.

Comment: @user415795 - to ammend on NullUserExceptions question, do you need `WHERE column LIKE '%WIS%' OR column LIKE '%SUN%'` or do you need `WHERE column LIKE '%WIS%SUN%'`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use SQLServer and each word in comma-separated string has 3 letters, you can do
`WHERE  'wis,sun' LIKE '%'+LEFT(T.ReceiptNo,3)+'%'` If you need more sophisticated logic, you probably have to implement it through UDF(for better performance in this case it's better to create CLR UDF).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a place where you would create dynamic sql. Each element in your string would turn into a new line of LIKE in your where clause. It'll end up looking like:

```
(
   T.ReceiptNo LIKE '%WIS%' 
OR T.ReceiptNo LIKE '%SUN%' 
)
```

How you go about doing this dependent on where you are building your SQL. Are you using a stored procedure or inline SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Below query will provide the desired result,

```
DECLARE @likeValue VARCHAR(5000),
    --@ReceiptNo VARCHAR(500),
    @selectSql VARCHAR(500),
    @sql VARCHAR(5000)

--SET @ReceiptNo ='wis,sun'
-- Put Select SQL
SET @selectSql = 'SELECT * FROM TableName AS T '
-- Splitting the string as required
SET @likeValue = REPLACE(@ReceiptNo, ',', '%'' OR T.ReceiptNo LIKE  ''%')
-- Making a single query by concatenating all
SET @sql = @selectSql + ' WHERE T.ReceiptNo LIKE ''%'+ @likeValue + '%'''
--Finally executing the sql query
EXEC(@sql)
```